# How can I avoid from turning mushrooms brown while freezing it?

Tags: storage-method, freezing, mushrooms

When you freeze mushrooms they will turn brown.  You can't keep them for long time in the fridge though. On the other hand I can't buy it everyday! I love mushrooms in anything and I want to have some always ready to cook. Any suggestions? Is the only way to buy it everyday? I don't like canned mushrooms or similar preservation methods.

Comment: If you bake them, you won't have to worry, because they are already brown!

Answer (score 6):

One suggestion is to buy dried mushrooms and rehydrate them when you need them.

As for freezing, as you probably know if you freeze them and thaw directly without any intervention you will probably get brown, mushy mushrooms.  There are a few ways to avoid this.

If you blanch the mushrooms first in some boiling water, then put them in an ice bath, that should stop the enzymes that cause the browning and also help with the texture some.  This method should also retain the most flavor of any of the preservation methods.

As a side note, I highly recommend going from freezer to cooking directly without thawing - this should reduce the amount of mushiness you will get.

I find that slicing and sauteing the mushrooms first in some oil or butter, then freezing them, works great for most uses, since sauteed is how I usually prefer my mushrooms anyway.  I just take them out of the freezer and throw them directly into the meal.

In my house the most common method is as I first mentioned, we buy dried portabellos etc and just rehydrate them into our meals.  However blanching and then freezing is often better for texture and taste, it just takes a little more time.

There are some great mushroom preservation methods available [on this site](http://www.nmmastergardeners.org/Fungi%20pages/Preserve%20Mushroom.htm).

Comment: How about boiling them with water and a little lemon juice?

Answer (score 2):

I have read that you need to [cook them prior to freezing](http://mushrooms.ca/blog/2009/05/feature-friday-freezing-fresh-mushrooms.html).

Summary of instructions:

1. Wash mushrooms (don't soak them, you don't want to take on extra water)
2. Pat Dry
3. Quickly sautee them with a bit of oil over medium high heat.
4. Allow to cool then transfer to a freezer container, removing as much air as possible
5. Like with freezing most things, excess air/moisture will speed up freezer burn.

As another alternative, to simply not buying fresh mushrooms daily is to keep dried mushrooms on hand.

Comment: There's a step missing or something: allow to cool from what? Washing? Patting dry?